# Underscore in emails

Tags: titles, affiliation

I am writing a paper and trying to write my email address, which contains underscore. My question is how to write underscore in email addresses?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{aip-cp}
 \begin{document} 
 \title{This is title} 
 \author{my name} 
 \eaddress{my\_name@yahoo.com}
 \affil{My Department} 
 \maketitle 
 \end{document}
```

Comment: `\_` is the command for underscores in text

Comment: Yes, but I am using `\eaddress{my\_name@yahoo.com}` and it appears like  my(Omega symbol)_name@yahoo.com

Comment: can you add an example ? when I try using simply `_` it works well...

Comment: Then of course we need more information about your document. Where does `\eaddress ` come from. Could you please provide a minimal example document that shows this problem

Comment: I am using `\documentclass{aip-cp}
\begin{document}
\title{This is title}
\author{my name}
\eaddress{my\_name@yahoo.com}
\affil{My Department}
\maketitle
\end{document}`

Comment: try this:  `\documentclass{aip-cp} 
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareUrlCommand\eaddress{\urlstyle{rm}}

\begin{document} 
\title{This is title} 
\author{my name} 
\eaddress{my_name@yahoo.com} 
\affil{My Department} 
\maketitle
 \end{document}`

Comment: @MedVall, it does not work.

Comment: @Sara, It works for me using both PDFLaTeX and XeLaTeX !. can you tell me what error you got when you compile it?

Comment: I got undefined control sequence <recently read> \DeclareUrlCommand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and then type the underscore as `\_`

```
   \documentclass{aip-cp} 
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
   \begin{document} 
   \title{This is title} 
   \author{my name} 
   \eaddress{my\_name@yahoo.com} 
   \affil{My Department} 
   \maketitle
   \end{document}
```